# Identity matrix when collecting column vector

Tags: matrices, education

I'd like to prove that:

$$ s \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) - \boldsymbol{A} \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) = \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) \, \left( s \, \boldsymbol{I} - \boldsymbol{A} \right)$$

where $s$ is a scalar, $Q$ is a column vector of dimension $n$, and $A$ is a square matrix $n \times n$.

My problem is to understand where identity matrix comes from. I tried to do a proof, but it is wrong: $Q^{-1}Q=I$ does not have meaning because $Q$ is a column vector, thus $Q^-1$ is absurd.

$$ s \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) - \boldsymbol{A} \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) = $$

$$ =\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}^{-1}(s) \left(s \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) - \boldsymbol{A} \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) \right)  = $$

$$=\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) \left( s \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}^{-1}(s) - \boldsymbol{A} \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}^{-1}(s) \right)  = $$

$$=\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) \, \left( s \, \boldsymbol{I} - \boldsymbol{A} \, \boldsymbol{I} \right) = $$

$$=\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) \, \left( s \, \boldsymbol{I} - \boldsymbol{A}  \right) $$

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we adopt the usual row- columns rule for the multiplication of a matrix and a vector, the correct result is:
$$
s\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) - \boldsymbol{A} \, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s) =  \, \left( s \, \boldsymbol{I} - \boldsymbol{A} \right)\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s)
$$

and the identity matrix comes from the fact that
$$
s\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s)=s\,({\bf I} \overrightarrow{\bf Q}(s))= (s \,{\bf I} \,)\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Q}}(s)
$$

Comment: If I have $Aq+qB$ with A and B matix and q vector, I can't collect q vector?

Comment: What do you mean by "collect q vector?"

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi. In general  the matrices multiplication is not commutative and, in a ring, we have **left** and **right** distributivity but not a ''mixed'' distributivity.  In this case, the $q$ in $Aq$ is a **column** vector, the $q$ is a **row** vector. So we cannot collect two objects that are not there same.

Comment: @EmilioNovati thank you for your clear reply.