# Collecting vector q in $Aq+qB$ with A and B matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to factor out a vector $q$ in the following expression:

$$Aq+qB$$

with matrices $A$ and $B$?

For example, $q(A+B)$ or $(A+B)q$?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you explain a bit what "collect q vector" means?

Comment: Hello @DietrichBurde I edited my question.

Comment: Do you mean factor?

Comment: If $q$ in $qB$ is a row vector, and in $Aq$ is a column, then you should have written it all as something like $Aq + (q^tB)^t$ or $(Aq)^t + q^tB$ (one can’t add a row and a column), where ${}^t$ is transpose. Then apply $(XY)^t = Y^tX^t$ to an arbitrary summand.

Comment: The question still is not clear (as you can see from the comments). I would guess, the answer is *no*; take $B=-A$. Furthermore, a bit more [context](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562983/identity-matrix-when-collecting-column-vector) in your question would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @DietrichBurde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arseniiv has pointed out your key problem. Let's first look at this a little more generally than you intended. Consider $A$ to be a $i \times j$ matrix, $q$ to be a $k \times l$ matrix, and $B$ to be an $m \times n$ matrix.

In order to multiply $Aq, A$ has to have as many columns as $q$ has rows. So $j = k$, and the result is an $i \times l$ matrix. In order to multiply $qB, q$ has to have as many columns as $B$ as rows, so $l = m$, and the result is a $k \times n$ matrix. In order to add $Aq$ and $qB$, the two matrices have to have the same dimensions, so $i = k$ and $l = n$. But that gives $i = j = k$ and $l = m = n$. $A$ is a $k \times k$ matrix, $q$ is a $k \times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

Since you call $q$ a vector, one of its dimensions must be $1$. If $q$ is a column vector, then $n = 1$ and $B$ is just a number. Therefore $qB = BI_kq$ and $$Aq + qB = (A + BI_k)q$$

If $q$ is a row vector, then $k = 1$ and $A$ is just a number. Therefore $Aq = qAI_n$ and $$Aq + qB = q(AI_n + B)$$

Comment: Thank @Paul Sinclait for your excellent explanation.